# What data structure could I use for counting occurrences of a country code?

Tags: java, data-structures

I need some kind of data structure don't know yet which would be most suitable.

Here is what I'm working with: I have a bunch rows of data processing and each row has its own country code.

I want to obtain as result how many times each country code repeats throughout the process.

Comment: @Ed Staub hi Ed no row does not mean a table row from database, it's actually data from the queue, arriving one by one as if it were database ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might try a [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).  With a HashMap, you can use the country code as the key, and the count of how many times each appears as the value stored in that key.  If you encounter a particular country code for the first time, insert it into the map with an initial value of 1; otherwise, increment the existing value.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (... record : records) {
    String countryCode = record.getCountryCode();

    int curVal;
    if (myMap.containsKey(countryCode)) {
        curVal = myMap.get(countryCode);
        myMap.put(countryCode, curVal + 1);
    } else {
        myMap.put(countryCode, 1);
    }
}

// myMap now contains the count of each country code, which
// can be used for whatever purpose needed.
```

Comment: In Java, you can't parameterize with raw numeric types. You'd have to use `Integer` instead of `int`.

Comment: @Dylan: Thanks!  My C#.Net background is definitely showing through :-)  I had to give it a second thought to remember that `String` starts with a capital S in Java..

Comment: Also, (and I know this is just an example) but doing all of the addition operations on an Integer object may not be optimal due to all of the autoboxing/auto-unboxing taking place.

Comment: Don't worry about optimal.  That won't kill your code.  Get it to work, measure it, and see if it affects performance before you dismiss something out of hand.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a HashMap with the country code as the key and the count as the value. Build the map from your collection and increment the count if it is already in the map.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Map using country code String as the key and the current count as the value.

You realize, of course, that you can get such a thing directly out of a SQL query:

```
select country_code, count(country_code)
from your_table
group by country_code
order by country_code
```

You'll get a ResultSet with country code and count pairs.  That's easy to load into a Map.

Comment: hi, I'm not working with SQL here. So the map should retain the latest inserted value? I though Map doesn't allow duplicates hence inserting new key value pairs didn't make sense. But if that is true than I should look no further

Comment: Yes, it makes perfect sense.  You're inserting a new count as values come in, so you have to do some work to update it.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer with something other than [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

- If your country code list is or can easily be turned into a not very sparse numeric sequence, try a `int[]` or `long[]`.
- If your country code range is sparse, but don't have many elements, create a `CountryCode` [enum](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) And use a [EnumMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) to store the amounts:

**Example:**

```
Map<CountryCode, Long> countryCodeAppearances = 
       new EnumMap<CountryCode,Long>(CountryCode.class);
```

Lightweight data structures will perform better and impose less memory / garbage collection overhead. So, array should be the fastest. EnumMap is kind off a hidden gem that, under the right circumstances may also give you a performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

Guava offers the [`AtomicLongMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html)